# How to change Expire Date format in admin form magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, adminform, datepicker, dateformat

how can i change Expire Date format from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy in product form admin panel

[image]

Comment: @khaled is **Expire Date** is custom product attribute??

Comment: Can you please share your custom attribute name or code?

Answer (score 0):

> **Please add the below files to your module.**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_date" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Datetime</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier**

**Datetime.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class Datetime extends AbstractModifier
{
    protected $arrayManager;

    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = $this->updatetimeFormate($meta);

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    protected function updatetimeFormate(array $meta)
    {
        $fieldCode = 'Your_custom_attribute_name'; // add your attribute name here

        $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
        $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');

        if (!$elementPath) {
            return $meta;
        }

        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $containerPath,
            $meta,
            [
                'children'  => [
                    $fieldCode => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'default' => '',
                                    'options'       => [
                                        'dateFormat' > 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                                        'timeFormat' => 'HH:mm:ss',
                                        'showsTime' => true
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );


        return $meta;
    }
}
```